# Mostrar la página y continuar ejecutando código PHP después de enviar la respuesta y cerrar la conexión

Tags: php, phpmailer, php5

Tengo un formulario que guarda la información en la base de datos y eso me toma menos de 1 segundo y muestra un agradecimiento, pero esa información la quiero mandar por PhpMailer a 5 personas, eso me toma 18 segundos para que finalice de cargar la pagina  y muestre el agradecimiento.

Entonces pensaba hacer que solo muestre el agradecimiento y que se ejecute el archivo PHP, en segundo plano se podría decir, pero le tengo que enviar 2 variables.

Vi por internet soluciones usando shell, pero ¿no hay otra forma mas simple?

Comment: Podrías guardar los datos de los Mail pendientes de enviar en la bd y correr un cron job que ejecute un script que realice el envío de esos mail pendientes periódicamente

Comment: Creo que se puede poner que sea al preciso momento? , ya que esos email se necesitan al instante.

Comment: Por poder puedes ejecutar el cron job en periodos tan largos o cortos como necesites, eso sí se ha de tener en cuenta que el cron se ejecutará con el periodo indicado, independientemente de que haya o no pendientes. Otra opción podría ser lanzar un ajax por debajo después de enviar el formulario para que envíe el Mail y el usuario no esté con la página bloqueada mientras.

Comment: @Mariano perfecto, no pensen en esa opción pero la veo muy bien. te dejo mis puntos. Un saludo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías cerrar la conexión, haciendo que el cliente reciba la información, pero mantener la ejecución del script. Está explicado en el manual: [Manejo de conexiones](http://php.net/manual/es/features.connection-handling.php).

Código:

```
<?php

//El server va a cerrar la conexión
@ob_end_clean();
header('Connection: close');

//cuando el cliente cierre la conexión, que el script siga
ignore_user_abort(true);

//postergar la impresión
ob_start();


// TU PÁGINA
echo '<html><body>¡Gracias por enviar la info!</body></html>';


//enviar el contenido
header('Content-Length: ' . ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
@ob_flush();
flush();

//SIGUE EJECUTANDO
//Acá todo el código de lo que quieras seguir haciendo
//pero si se imprime algo acá, el cliente nunca lo va a ver
//    //Por ejemplo, podemos llamar a otro PHP
//    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/carpeta/enviar-mails.php');
//    //o podemos llamar a nuestra propiea función
miCodigo('sin imprimir, porque el cliente jamás lo verá');
```

Comment: Wuao, voy a probarlo y te digo !

Comment: una pregunta que viene hacer
 include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/carpeta/enviar-mails.php');?                   Realice lo que hicistes entonces si me resulto, pero no puse el include, sino hice que se mande los email.y si funciona, estara bien o debo usar ese include?

Comment: @FrancisYourem Esa línea era sólo un ejemplo de cómo llamar a otro archivo PHP, porque no sé cómo está organizado tu script, pero no es necesario que lo uses... Lo que hace esa línea es ejecutar un php que se encuentra en `/carpeta/enviar-mails.php` dentro de la raíz de tu webserver (del *document root*)... Sin embargo, está perfecto que ejecutes el código para enviar los mails directamente dentro del mismo archivo en vez de llamar a otro archivo.

Comment: Si, muchas gracias!
Saludos